# Fitting a deep learning model with a different batch of data every epoch Keras Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a deep learning model which consists of various layers. I am running it for 20 epochs. I want to divide the whole data into 20 batches and each batch will go in each epoch. So, if I have 20 slices of the data, is there a way to fit each slice in each epoch.

`text_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)`
The name of the model class is text_model which I want to fit each epoch.
I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: a Keras `Model` won't allow you to run such a computation. Instead as suggested by @Massimo Zambelli, implement a custom training loop. `Model.fit()` will slice the data into batches ( where the size of each batch is determined by the batch size ) and train the model on each of these batches, in one single epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to pass a different batch for each epoch? By definition, an epoch is a pass through the *whole* dataset, and at each step of the epoch we pass a different batch of data. This is what you want to do, except it happens automatically *within* each epoch.

If for some strange reason you still want to use a unique batch per epoch, every time different, you can just call `.fit()` in a loop, using every time a different slice of the original dataset as input. It will be unnecessarily slow tho, and won't provide any additional feature with respect to just fit the entire dataset with batches of size (number of samples / number of batches you want)

Comment: Hello Massimo, thanks for your response. For my special case, yes I want to train a different slice of the data for each epoch. The way you are saying is fitting the model in a loop which means fitting the model n times. I want to fit the model once wherein each epoch, I want to take different slice of the data. I will appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, it's somehow against the very definition of epoch. Calling fit a bunch of times will not re-fit the model from scratch, since the weights are obviously kept after each fit (thus, the overall effect is the same as that of a unique fit of multiple epochs). The only problem could be with the internal states of the optimizer (see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/428) for instance). 

Another option can still be writing a custom training loop, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch).

Comment: It is possible with pure tensorflow implementation, where you can dynamically provide the samples you would want to pass at each epoch. 
For example when you initialize a cnn model with the model input (None, 150, 150, 3) this is what you can do! I dont think Kera model trainer gives you this flexibility. Cheers!